# Push notifications in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am at the final stage of my codename one app now and this final stage is to implement push notifications.

I need some help on how to implement the client side for push notifications.

I have followed the section in the developer guide and my main class implements PushCallback.

I also have the relevant methods implemented as below:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() ->  Display.getInstance().registerPush());

    showHomeForm();
}

@Override
public void push(String value) {
    Dialog.show("Received Push", value, "OK", null);  
}

@Override
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
    Dialog.show("Push Registered", "Device ID: " + deviceId + "\nDevice Key: " + Push.getDeviceKey() , "OK", null);
}

@Override
public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {
    Dialog.show("Push Error", "" + error, "OK", null);
}
```

My understanding is that the registeredForPush method should be invoked when calling the registerPush method. When I start the app the registeredForPush method is not called and the registerPush method seems to do nothing.

What is incorrect in my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `Dialog` in these callbacks as a dialog call is blocking and might cause a failure because of the nature of these API's e.g. an API can be invoked when the app is minimized.

`registerPush()` triggers the registration and should eventually invoke either the registered or the error method.

I'm guessing you are running on the simulator where push isn't actually implemented. You can use the new push console that allows you to simulate it by invoking the registered callbacks and send push messages to the simulator. These will only work on the devices.

Comment: I am using the simulator so that’s where it’s going wrong! I’ll check it today and confirm this. Thanks